# How to programmatically control iPhone or device speaker in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am creating a **conference app for iOS 9**, which makes a call. Once call is made it takes user to native iPhone screen. Later user can come back to our app to do various tasks, when call is running in background. We need to give a user option to **control that iPhone speakers On/Off from our app** itself.

But unfortunately, we are not able to find any document or sample on ths. 
Kindly advice us how to achieve ths functionality.

Comment: From " Once call is made it takes user to native iPhone screen", does that means the user will not be in your APP, but rather "Phone" app?

Comment: I dont understand, can you insert some draft about your project..give more details, too generic..

Comment: Were you able to achieve this ?